# Calculating VAT

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, forms

I'm creating a simple web app that takes two values, outputs a total, then displays VAT of 20% in the VAT field (to clarify, this shows 20% of the total previously calculated) then it should have a final grand total field which adds the total to the VAT, however I haven't gotten round to this part as I'm having difficulty calculating the VAT in my code, this is what I have thus far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    Value 1: <input type="text" name="val1"><br>
    Value 2: <input type="text" name="val2"><br>
    Total: <input type="text" name="sum"><br>
      VAT:<input type="text" name="vat"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="sumTotal() + vatCalc()">

</form>

<script>
    function sumTotal() {
        let val1 = document.getElementsByName("val1")[0].value;
        let val2 = document.getElementsByName("val2")[0].value;
        let sum = Number(val1) + Number(val2);
        document.getElementsByName("sum")[0].value = sum;
    }
    function vatCalc () {
    //  let vat= document.getElementsByName("vat")
      var sumVat = 20;
         let vat = (sum/100)*(sumVat+100);
         document.getElementsByName("vat")[0].value = vat;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated please, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've edited your functions so now sumtotal calls your vat function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        Value 1: <input type="text" name="val1"><br>
        Value 2: <input type="text" name="val2"><br>
        Total: <input type="text" name="sum"><br>
        VAT:<input type="text" name="vat"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="sumTotal()">

    </form>

    <script>


    function sumTotal() {
        let val1 = document.getElementsByName("val1")[0].value;
        let val2 = document.getElementsByName("val2")[0].value;
        let sum = Number(val1) + Number(val2);
        document.getElementsByName("sum")[0].value = sum;
        vatCalc(sum);
    }
    function vatCalc (sum) {
    //  let vat= document.getElementsByName("vat")
        var sumVat =0.20;
         let vat = sumVat*sum;
         document.getElementsByName("vat")[0].value = vat;
}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```